# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un problema con el javascript, más exactamente con la propiedad .classList.toggle
En teoría estoy definiendo bien los objetos, pero a la hora de hacer click, una vez compilado, en la pagina me salta el siguiente error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
Y no se el porque. He buscado y no he encontrado una respuesta, en la Api de javascript se encuentra la propiedad, así que no creo que sea porque ha sido eliminada, pero si hubiera sido eliminada ¿Cómo se haría? ¿Hay algo que haya que incluir y me este comiendo? O simplemente no estoy definiendo los objetos de forma que sepa al objeto al que me refiero.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://64.media.tumblr.com/bd1b0d977b3e43cc5645297d5322662c/tumblr_ndyybljlWc1rvnh7zo1_r1_500.gif");
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
            /* Centrar elemento dentro de main */
.main {
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 left: 0; right: 0;
 top: 0; bottom: 0;
 width: 1404px/*550px*/;
 height: 658px/*315px*/; line-height: 50px; /* Con «line-height» con el mismo valor numérico de la altura centras horizontalmente el texto */

}
.video{
    width: 1370px;
 height: 770px;
}
.navigation{
    position: fixed;
    inset: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
.navigation.open{
    width: 250px;
}
.navigation .menuToggle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 0 23px;
}
.navigation .menuToggle ::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #333;
    transform: translateY(-8px);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.navigation.open .menuToggle ::before{
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(45deg);
}
.navigation .menuToggle ::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #333;
    transform: translateY(8px);
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-shadow: 0 -8px 0 #333;
}
.navigation.open .menuToggle ::after{
transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-45deg);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo1.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spectral+SC:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Prueba</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="menuToggle">
                <ul>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.menuToggle');
            const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigator');
            menuToggle.onclick = function(){
                navigation.classList.toggle('open')
            }
        </script>
        <div class="main">
            <iframe class="video" width="560" height="315" src="" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No será porque estas asignando la constante navigation a un elemento que no existe?  Fíjate que pones la clase `.navigator` dentro de su querySelector, la cual no existe en tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien te comentaron, tienes un error en el `querySelector`, precisamente aquí, ya que no posees ningún elemento con la clase `navigator`:

```
const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigator');
```

Intuyendo que quieres hacer referencia al div contenedor del menuToggle, que lo defines en JS en la línea anterior, deberías redefinirlo así:

```
const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation');
```

Coincidiendo el nombre con el `div` declarado anteriormente:

```
<div class="navigation">
        <div class="menuToggle">
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cuando son errores tipográficos no solemos poner respuestas, con los comentarios lo aclaramos. Si el OP confirma que solo era eso estas preguntas terminan cerradas porque las preguntas con solo errores tipográficos no ayudan a nadie ni a nada ni son útiles para nadie más que el que lo preguntó.

Comment: Lo siento, no lo sabía.

Comment: No te preocupes, ni lo sientas, solo te informaba, pasa a menudo :-)  Normalmente son rápidamente cerradas, o bien las elimina el propio OP cuando se da cuenta. Esta se habia quedado zombie esperando alguna respuesta del OP, pero espero que alguien la reporte (a mi no me deja porque me equivoqué al hacerlo) y asi vaya a revisión y la cierren si el OP no dice nada nuevo.